# How i can change the User-Agent Header in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 APIM has a default User-Agent header which is:

```
Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO
```

I want to change it to something else, so i have added header mediation from the publisher run time configuration but no luck, also i tried to add this line `http.user.agent.preserve=true` in `passthru-http.properties` as many people said but whenever i restart the server it is removed from the file.

How I can accomplish it ?
I am using wso2am-3.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In APIM 3.2.0, we use `deployment.toml` file to add/modify configurations. If you edit the configuration files directly, it will be overridden by the configs in the deployment.toml during server startup. Try adding the below values in `deployment.toml` found inside `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/`

```
[passthru_http]
'http.user.agent.preserve'=true
```